# Unable to locate Python.h despite having it in the system (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I have Anaconda 3.6 and I'm trying to compile Pycaffe (from Caffe framework) but I get the following error:

```
python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:1:52: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I have installed the python-dev packages specific to Python 3.6 with `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev` and when I run `locate Python.h` it returns:

```
/home/jdevezas/.local/share/Trash/info/Python.h.trashinfo
/home/jdevezas/anaconda/bin/Python.h
/home/jdevezas/anaconda/include/python3.6m/Python.h
/home/jdevezas/anaconda/pkgs/python-3.6.0-0/include/python3.6m/Python.h
/home/jdevezas/anaconda/pkgs/python-3.6.4-hc3d631a_1/include/python3.6m/Python.h
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.5m/Python.h
/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/include/lldb/Interpreter/ScriptInterpreterPython.h
```

The correct PATH to the Anaconda folder is specified in my .bashrc file with:

```
export PATH="home/jdevezas/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: should that be `export PATH="/home/jdevezas/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` (needs a slash at the beginning of the string)?

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. It that were to be the problem wouldn't it interfere with me calling python on the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you faced the same problem but in my case.

After installing the python-dev packages via -

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

I had `python3.6` installed but the defaults were pointing to `python3.5`.

```
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
# $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
# $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
```

Can you confirm?